# What drivers to install on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008, drivers, chipset

I just installed Win 2008 R2 on the Mainboard with the [AMD 785G](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_700_chipset_series#785G) chipset.

Should I install any chipset drivers?

Should I install the ATI Catalyst drivers? Are there performance benefits (I use Remote Desktop only)?

Answer (score 1):

RDP uses it's own video drivers. So the catalyst would only matter when you're logged in locally.

> "On the server, RDP uses its own video
>   driver to render display output by
>   constructing the rendering information
>   into network packets by using RDP
>   protocol and sending them over the
>   network to the client. On the client,
>   RDP receives rendering data and
>   interprets the packets into
>   corresponding Microsoft Win32 graphics
>   device interface (GDI) API calls. For
>   the input path, client mouse and
>   keyboard events are redirected from
>   the client to the server. On the
>   server, RDP uses its own on-screen
>   keyboard and mouse driver to receive
>   these keyboard and mouse events."

[link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383015(VS.85).aspx)

Chipset drivers ... I've always installed them if they were avalible, never really bothered to do a before and after benchmark. Does anyone have hard numbers on this?

If you can't find them, it may not be a big deal, unless there's a specific feature that you need from the chipset. (Of course, one of those features may increase performance ...)

Answer (score 1):

I do the same as Joseph Kern - install them if available but not fuss otherwise. I'm quite happy to log on locally with nothing more than standard VGA drivers if that's all I have. Over RDP it really makes no difference because the server side drivers play no part in the video rendering on the client.

I once had to go through the exercise of proving that because a senior manager insisted in trying to watch video clips in an RDP session and, not surprisingly, found the performance inadequate. Even replacing the server's video card with a top notch one, complete with the latest drivers, made absolutely no difference. The only up side to that was that I got a new video card for my workstation out of it.